# Exclude folder when searching files in working directory

Tags: search, replace, working-directory, vimgrep

I'm working in a react project and opened vim from the root folder. When I'm using

```
:vimgrep /pattern/ **
```

I just can search everywhere, but I want to search everywhere except the 'node_modules' folder.

How can I create a mapping to exclude specific folder names permanently from searching?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try the following:

```
set wildignore=*/node_modules/*
```

I just played a little with `wildignore`, so I don't know if it works in all cases.

E.g. if you do a

```
:vimgrep /pattern/ node_modules/**
```

It will find nothing, as all files below `node_modules` are ignored.

See `:help wildignore`.

---

Update:

The option `wildignore` is a comma-separated list of pattern. To ignore multiple directories use:

```
set wildignore=*/node_modules/*,*/target/*,*/tmp/*
```

Comment: Is there a way that I can exclude multiple folders?